# How can I efficiently remove multiple deployed websites from Cloudflare?

Tags: web-hosting, cloudflare

I've been managing several websites through Cloudflare, and due to a restructuring process, I need to remove all of these websites from the Cloudflare platform. I've explored the Cloudflare dashboard but haven't found an option to bulk delete or remove multiple sites at once.

Is there a recommended or efficient way to remove multiple deployed websites from Cloudflare in one go rather than individually? I have a screenshot listing all the websites I need to remove for reference: [image: Here is a photo of my deployed websites on cloudflare]

It seems there isn't a button provided to remove the sites, and when attempting to deploy a new site, I'm unable to initiate a fresh deployment without reconnecting my GitHub. I'd actually prefer the option to reconnect to GitHub each time for this process.